# Fitting Sounds Waves with Sines/Cosines

Tags: harmonic-analysis

I am trying to model sound waves with a series of sines and cosines but I am not sure what the best way to find the best deterministic sine/cosine combination that best fits the data. What are some methods to find, $cos(2{\pi}x/f+shift) $ the shift value to best overlap the sound waves with the sine/cosine function. You could have a sine/cosine with the right frequency/periodicity but simply due to the wrong shift not fully minimizing the error between the sound and the sine/cosine

[image]

Comment: Use a fast Fourier transform.

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you for your response Copper.hat but after I do a FFT what do I do with the output? I did a FFT on the sound waves and I got squiggles going up and down around 0, what do I do with this output?